# Unable to deserialise a nested class with NSCoding

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a complex class with many nested classes to several levels deep which is serialised and stored in CoreData table. The problem is that, since upgrading to Swift 3 instances of the class cannot be deserialised, failing when trying to decode instances of the nested classes.

To illustrate the problem create a class definition with an inner class which implements NSCoding:

import Foundation

```
class Foo : NSObject, NSCoding {

    class Bar : NSObject, NSCoding {
        var x : Int

        init(x:Int) {
            self.x = x
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.x = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "x")
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encode(x, forKey:"x")
        }
    }

    var bar:Bar

    init(x:Int) {
        self.bar = Bar(x: x)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.bar = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "bar") as! Bar
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(bar, forKey:"bar")
    }
}
```

Then construct the unit tests:

```
import XCTest
@testable import SerializationDemo

class SerializationDemoTests: XCTestCase {

     func fileURL() -> URL {

        let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        return dir.appendingPathComponent("foo.dat")

    }

    func testSerialize() {
        let foo = Foo(x:42)
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foo)

        let url = fileURL()

        do {
            try data.write(to: url)
        } catch {
            XCTFail("\(error)")
        }
    }

    func testDeserialise() {
        let url = fileURL()
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let myfoo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Foo
            XCTAssertEqual(myfoo.bar.x, 42)
        } catch {
            XCTFail("\(error)")
        }

    }
}
```

Now run the two tests in one session by selecting the test case itself. This will work as expected serialising and deserialising the object correctly.

Now try running the two unit tests independently. First serialise. The deserialise. The second test fails with

> failed: caught "NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException", "***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (_TtCC17SerializationDemo3Foo3Bar) for key (bar); the class may
>   be defined in source code or a library that is not linked"

One solution is to restructure the code so that all the inner classes are top level instead, which would also require renaming those classes to make them globally unique in the application. I would rather not have to rework the code in this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure this is a bug in Swift 3, possibly an attempt to optimise the class loader. It seems the class loader won't load an inner class directly during deserialisation, before that class definition has been loaded by other means.

In the sample tests adding a line

```
_ = Foo(x: 0)
```

to testDeserialise() fixes the problem. Apparently by pre-loading the necessary class definitions.

I was able to fix the problem in my app by adding some code to the complex class to preload an instance of each of the inner classes recursively the first time an attempt is made to deserialise an instance:

Basically:

```
if !preloaded {
   for x in  allElements() {
       _ = x.allOperations()
   }
   preloaded = true
}
```

Where allElements() returns a list instantiating one instance of each inner class and allOperations() returns all inner classes of each of those.

**UPDATE**

I have submitted a bug report with Apple #30034842

Apple engineering have also suggested another temporary workaround. To use `NSCoder.decodeObject(of: [AnyClass]?, forKey: String)` when the decoding object knows the possible classes which could be decoded.

They have also noted:

> You should also assign Bar an @objc name (e.g. @objc(Bar)); we do not
>   guarantee the stability of Swift mangled names over time — for
>   backwards and forwards compatibility, you should give it a canonical
>   name.

**UPDATE** Mar 2018

This is fixed in Xcode 9, even when compiling with Swift Language Version 3.2. In addition assigning @objc names is enforced at runtime during encoding.